# Simple pascal about selecting variables

Tags: pascal

Lets say there are 10 variables, each have a number attributed to them by the user.
I want the program to add only the ones > than 20, how exactly do I do that??

Comment: Check IF variable > 20 THEN Sum BECOMES Sum  PLUS variable  Be careful with >20 and >=20.

Comment: I still cant figure it out

Comment: When you say *each have a number attributed to them by the user* are you wanting to know how they get input by the user? It's quite unclear what you're really asking for. What you want to do is (1) learn how to do *arrays*, and set up an array of 10 numbers (you need to decide if the numbers are integer or floating point and choose a number type for them), then (2) read the user numbers into the array, and (3) initialize a sum variable to 0, and use a `for` loop that checks each of the array elements for a value > 20 (`if num[i] > 20 then sum := sum + 1;`). You should do a Pascal tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I do not know exactly what you are asking for, here's both options:

```
program name;
var numbers:array[10]of integer;
    sum:integer;
begin
   sum:=0;
   for i:=1 to sizeof(numbers)do begin
      writeln('Insert a number');
      readln(numbers[i]);
   end;
   for i:=1 to sizeof(numbers)do begin
      if numbers[i]>20 then sum:=sum+numbers[i];
   end;
end.
```

Or

```
program name;
var numbers:array of integer;
    validate:integer;
begin
   for i:=1 to 10 do begin
      writeln('Insert a number');
      readln(validate);
      if validate>20 then numbers[i]:=validate;
   end;
end.
```